# Iterating over expanding list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose I have a list:

```
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...]
```

I want to iterate over this list in an expanding manner so that every iteration inside a loop I get:

1 iteration: `[0]`

2 iteration: `[0, 1]`

3 iteration: `[0, 1, 2]`

4 iteration: `[0, 1, 2, 3]`
...

This is basically to emulate a real time growing time series.

I pass this slice of lst to another function to make some computations.

Now I do it like this:

```
for i in range(1, len(lst)):
  my_func(lst[:i], other_variables)
```

Boy this is slow.  My list has above 1M elements.  I know that slicing makes a shallow copy of list, maybe I can somehow avoid copies, or use some kind of different approach.

I also tried this:

```
lst2 = []

for i in range(len(lst)):
  lst2.append(lst[i])
  my_func(lst2, other_variables)
```

A little bit better but still pretty slow.

I also tried deque() instead of list.

Comment: Are you sure there's much to gain on that front? What I mean is that if my_func is 100X the time consumer, then you've got a limited amount of speed to add by being smart with the list-handling. Try profiling the code?

Comment: Slicing a list is pretty fast. Unless ``my_func`` is *very* quick to execute, creating the list slice should not be significant overhead. Rather, executing ``my_func`` a million times will take some time. Have you profiled your code to make sure slicing is actually the issue?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi `lst[:k]` takes O(k) time, so iterating over all the prefixes will take quadratic time.

Comment: @chepner Well, sure it does, but it's still pretty fast. Slicing a million-element list takes 5.66 ms in the worst case on my system. The constant on that quadratic term means it should be negligible in practice. Since ``my_func`` receives the ``k`` elements from ``lst[:k]``, it's presumably O(k) anyways – so the code is quadratic no matter what.

Comment: `deque` allows you to insert at *either* end of a sequence efficiently. `deque.append` is no more efficient than `list.append`; it's `deque.appendleft` that is much more efficient than `list.insert(0,...)`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Depends on what `my_func` does with the list. But `my_func` almost certainly *becomes* the bottleneck after you eliminate slicing.

Comment: If you have control over `my_func`, you might consider passing `lst` and `i` as separate arguments, if that will let you avoid creating a slice altogether. (Maybe `my_func` itself only cares about the last 3 elements of the prefix, regardless of its size? The point being, there's only so much you can do while treating `my_func` as a black box.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `i` gets bigger, `lst[:i]` gets more and more expensive. But you don't need to create a new slice at each iteration; just append the next value of `lst` to a pre-existing prefix.

```
pfx = []
for c in lst:
    pfx.append(c)
    my_func(pfx, other_variables)
```

You could use `itertools.accumualte`, except Python doesn't have a nice *expression* for appending a value to a list and returning the updated list. `pfx + [c]` is just as slow `lst[:i]`.

Comment: Isn't that the same as their last code block?

Comment: Almost. It does avoid an extra call to `lst.__getitem__`, but there's no other unavoidable cost to eliminate, unless `my_func` itself can be optimized.

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution.  On top of that my_func was doing funny stuff.  Thank you.

Comment: @IgnasNevinskas Did you test the performance by taking `append` outside as mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @AKS yes, it is indeed even better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On top of what has been mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68301873/iterating-over-expanding-list/68302015#68302015), we can try to [avoid dots](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Avoiding_dots...) to improve the performance.

```
lst2 = []
append = lst2.append
for c in lst:
    append(c)
    my_func(lst2, other_variables)
```

We can see the performance gain with a mocked `my_func`:

```
def my_func(kt):
    pass

def method1():
    lst2 = []
    for c in lst:
        lst2.append(c)
        my_func(lst2)
        
def method2():
    lst2 = []
    append = lst2.append
    for c in lst:
        append(c)
        my_func(lst2)
```

```
In [11]: %timeit method1()
84.8 ms ± 4.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [12]: %timeit method2()
67 ms ± 262 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Very interesting optimization, haven't heard of this one before.  Thanks!